# ios - how to get y coordinate of a cell wrt. screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

- For eg. I have a table view with 10 cells of 50px height
- When the table view is first displayed, cell 5 has `y coordinate` of 200
- Now I scroll the table view and cell 5 is first visible cell on screen.
- Excluding, navBar of 40px, *theoretical* `y coord` of cell 5 is 40 wrt. screen. Right?

How can I get the value?

I tried `cell.frame.origin.y`, but it gives the starting `y` (200)

Comment: Any reason why you wish to get the y-coord of the cell? If you can specify your use case, you might get a helpful answer

Comment: @lostInTransit so, I am implement an autoComplete functionality for a particular textField. I want to tie the tableView for autoComplete data right below the textField. FOr the same, I need to know the textFields y Coord---makes sense??